# counting the number of arrays in a php decoded string

Tags: php, arrays, count, decode

I have two json decoded strings:

```
{"Coords":[{"Accuracy":"66","Latitude":"88","Longitude":"99","Timestamp":"100"}]}
```

and I have another string

```
 {"Coords":[{"Accuracy":"222","Latitude":"333","Longitude":"444","Timestamp":"2013"},{"Accuracy":"3434","Latitude":"565","Longitude":"676","Timestamp":"7878"}]}.
```

Is there a way to be able to echo that the first string has 1 array and the second string has 2? My method was as following:

```
$Json_String=($_POST['Json']);                                                               $Json_Decoded= json_decode($Json_String, true);                                            echo count(json_decode($Json_String, true));
```

where $Json_String is just what I'm pasting into a text field for now for testing purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do,

```
json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

for each string that will return you array. You can then count the length of array easily.

Comment: @ chandresh_cool I used the following code:    $Json_String=($_POST['Json']);
$Json_Decoded= json_decode($Json_String, true);
echo count(json_decode($Json_String, true));  But when I paste in the first string above, I get 1 and when I paste in the second string above I still get 1

Comment: You have to pass key of each array like echo count($arr['Coords']));

Comment: @user2363025 try the one which I said echo count($arr['Coords']));

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to kown the length try this:

```
    echo substr_count (' {"Coords":[{"Accuracy":"222","Latitude":"333","Longitude":"444","Timestamp":"2013"},{"Accuracy":"3434","Latitude":"565","Longitude":"676","Timestamp":"7878"}]}.','Accuracy');
```